# Visual Studio custom properties dialog

Tags: visual-studio

I'm familiar with how to include properties of a user control in the Properties Window of Visual Studio.  Can anyone tell me how to create a custom dialog, similar to the color picker for BackgroundColor, for a user control?  I have a control with many properties and a "Control Builder" form would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for something [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164048.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx). A walkthrough is available at msdn, [Walkthrough: Implementing a UI Type Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx).